# Filtering a list based on dropdown value equaling database column value

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an MVC web page using C# and Razor syntax which is displaying a list of results brought back from the database and I want to filter the results with a dropdown menu.

Basically I want to only show the results which has a column value that equals the value of the dropdown menu. My only problem is that the column is a BIT data type and I just can't get it to work.

I've tried converting the value of the dropdown to bool but this doesn't work either. I'm not at work right now so can't post any code sorry.

The way I initially query the database is using a search string and basically comparing the different columns to the search string and also whether the search string = "" or is null. I have just tacked the dropdown menu query on to the end of this search string select query as it seems the only place it could go and it is something like this -

```
from db(db.Name.Contains(searchString) && db.InUse.Equals(dropdownValue))
select db
```

I know that's not exactly right but you hopefully get the idea. And just to clarify, it's the InUse.Equals that I'm having trouble with as InUse is a BIT data type and dropdownValue is an INT and doesn't even work when converted to BOOL. I get no errors and the page loads but it doesn't actually filter the results.

Any help would be great and I'll try update the post tomorrow with actual code.

Comment: I can't quite tell if you are looking for a javascript solution to simply hide results when you select something in a dropdown because you're showing C# code here.

Comment: Are you expecting the dropdown to fire an ajax request to some controller to update this list you have?

Comment: What do you mean by "InUse is a BIT data type"? [bit datatype in SQL maps to Boolean in the .NET Framework as seen here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm wanting the dropdown list to work in the same way that the search string does, basically query each row in the database to see if the value of the 'InUse' column is either 1 or 0. I'm not keen on doing an AJAX request as I'd have to change the search string also wouldn't I? I didn't think about doing it in a hide/show way with Javascript so that could be an option. But yes ideally a C# solution would be the best for me.

I mean that the 'InUse' column in the database is of a bit datatype, so either 0,1 or null.

Comment: What values are passed to the controller for dropdownValue? zero and one? Have you tried converting dropdownValue to a temporary boolean variable, and then do a direct compare on that value  db.InUse == tempBoolean ?

Comment: Thanks seagulledge for putting me on to that track, no value was being passed for the dropdown. Fixing that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty basic example that could be used to show how to filter out elements in a collection based on values in a controller method.

The HttpGet just returns the whole list, but the HttpPost will filter the list based on the values in the form, and return the filtered list as the model for the view.

## Demo.cshtml

```
@model List<ServiceCatalog.Models.DemoClass>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Demo";
}

<h2>Demo</h2>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>InUse</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var m in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@m.InUse</td>
            <td>@m.Name</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2" for="Name">Seach String:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" value="" name="Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2" for="InUse">InUse:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control" name="InUse">
                    <option value="true">True</option>
                    <option value="false">False</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

## DemoClass.cs

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean InUse { get; set; }
}
```

## DemoController.cs

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Demo()
    {
        var demoList = GetListOfDemoClass().ToList();
        return View(demoList);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Demo([Bind(Include = "Name,Inuse")]DemoClass demoC)
    {
        var demoList = (from db in GetListOfDemoClass()
                        where (demoC.Name == null || db.Name.Contains(demoC.Name))
                            && db.InUse.Equals(demoC.InUse)
                        select db).ToList();

        return View(demoList);
    }

    private IEnumerable<DemoClass> GetListOfDemoClass()
    {
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = false, Name = "Thing 1" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = true, Name = "Dog 2" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = false, Name = "Place 3" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = true, Name = "Raptor 4" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = false, Name = "Person 5" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = true, Name = "Hateful 6" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = false, Name = "Cat 7" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = true, Name = "Mango 8" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = false, Name = "Bird 9" };
        yield return new DemoClass() { InUse = true, Name = "Caller 10" };
    }
}
```

Comment: I found my issue. In the end I wasn't actually getting the value from the dropdown, I had to change the values to "True" and "False" and that sorted it.